# How to flush readable stream internal queue with every pull?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, stream

In the API Route I have the following:

```
function iteratorToStream(iterator: AsyncGenerator<Uint8Array, void, undefined>) {
  const readStream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> = new ReadableStream(
    {
      async pull(controller) {
        const { value, done } = await iterator.next()
        if (done) {
          controller.close()
        } else {
          controller.enqueue(value)
        }
      },
    },
    {
      highWaterMark: 1,
    }
  )
  return readStream;
}

const encoder = new TextEncoder()

async function* makeIterator() {
  yield encoder.encode('HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld\n');
  yield encoder.encode('HelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorldHelloWorld\n');
  await sleep(1000);
  ...
}

export async function POST() {
  const iterator = makeIterator()
  const stream = iteratorToStream(iterator)

  return new Response(stream)
}
```

And on the client

```
function logStream(splitOn: string) {
    let buffer = '';

    return new TransformStream({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
            console.log(`
              logging chunk: ${chunk}  
              buffer: ${buffer}
            `);
            buffer += chunk;
            controller.enqueue(buffer);
        },
        flush(controller) {
            if (buffer) controller.enqueue(buffer);
        }
    });
}

await fetch('/route')
  .then(response => {
    const reader = body
      .pipeThrough(logStream)
      .getReader()
    return reader.read()
  })
```

However it appears that the queue never flushes without the iterator finishing.
I'm just trying to read each message individually.
I've also tried using the `ReadableStream` constructor with a `start` function but that doesn't seem to work either.
I've also tried the byobReader but that doesn't seem to work either.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks